# Direcionando para duas páginas

Tags: javascript, html

Estou trabalhando em algumas atualizações e preciso que minha função JavaScript abra uma nova guia com um boleto e volte para outra depois que eu clicar em gerar boleto. Ela abre a nova guia, mas não volta para a página escolher_estab.php, não emite erro nenhum também.
No Snippet ele mostra a página após 5 segundos, mas aqui no meu projeto ele executa apenas o window.open. 
Segue Código:

```js
function myFunction() {
   var valorBoleto = document.getElementById('valor').value; // joga o valor na variavel valorBoleto
   var dataBoletoString = document.getElementById('data_venc').value; // joga a data na variavel dataBoletoString
   var dataBoleto = new Date(dataBoletoString);
   dataBoleto.setDate(dataBoleto.getDate() + 1);
   var dataBoletoSegundos = dataBoleto.getTime();
   var dataHoje = new Date();
   var dataHojeSegundos = dataHoje.getTime();
   if (valorBoleto <= 0){
    alert("Valor inválido! Insira o valor do boleto.");
   }else{
    var res = window.confirm("O valor do boleto é: R$ "+ valorBoleto + ". Está correto?");
    if (res == true){
     if(dataBoletoSegundos >= dataHojeSegundos){
      var dataCorreta = confirm("O vencimento deste boleto é dia: "+ dataBoleto.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR") + " , está correto?")
      if(dataCorreta == true){
       setTimeout("document.location = 'http://www.guj.com.br/java/207585-comparando-datas-javascript'",5000);
       window.open("http://g1.globo.com/index.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbar=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=500, height=400");
      }
     }else{
      alert("O sistema não aceita datas anteriores ao dia de hoje.");
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

```html
<body oncontextmenu='return false' onselectstart='return false' ondragstart='return false'>  <!-- Não deixa o usuário clicar com o botão direito na página -->
  <div class="container clearfix">
   <?php
    include "header.php";
   ?>
   <div class="recuperar_usuario_senha">
    <form method="post" action="?acao=confirmar">
     <h1>Enviar boleto <em>SICLOP</em></h1>
     <h2> para <?php echo $nome_estab?></h2>
     <input type="password" name="estab" id="estab" value="<?php echo $nome_estab ?>" style="display:none"/> <!-- Nome do estabelecimento invisível para o usuário, para podermos pegar depois na ação GET -->
     <h2>Digite o valor do boleto:</h2>
     <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor"/>
     <h2> Digite a data de vencimento: </h2>
     <input type="date" name="data_venc" id="data_venc"/>
     <h2>Informações Adicionais</h2>
     <textarea cols="45" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea" maxlength="225"></textarea>
     </br><input onClick="myFunction()" type="image" src="img/gera_boleto.png" value="Confirmar" id="gera_boleto">
    </form>
   </div>
   <?php
    include "footer.php";
   ?>
  </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código funcionou aqui, testei tanto no Firefox quanto no Chrome.

Para desencargo de consciência (e facilidade de debug), coloquei a função de redirecionamento separada:

```
function redirBoleto() {
    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        document.location = 'http://www.guj.com.br/java/207585-comparando-datas-javascript';
    }, 5000);
    window.open("http://g1.globo.com/index.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbar=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=500, height=400");
}
```

A janela é aberta instantaneamente e, após 05 segundos, a página é redirecionada para a outra URL.

Tente utilizar a aba "Network" do console (Ctrl+Shift+I) e ver se ele registra a requisição do "location", caso ainda não funcione.

Comment: Legal. Valeu pela ajuda, mas acabei utilizando uma outra estratégia. Chamei a ação do form e ela me redireciona para uma página que possui as informações para o envio do boleto, ai, depois que ele executa esse código de envio, ele redireciona novamente. Funcionou assim e até ficou melhor pois ele informa se o e-mail foi ou não enviado.